# Simba error loading metadata

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, simba

I am using Simba ODBC driver to connect to a MongoDB database from Tableau. I use default config and get an Error: *There was an error loading metadata:*

That's it. No details. I manage to connect to other databases from the same MongoDB server, but not to the one I need.

Does Simba have some logs somewhere? Where or what should I check for details or for a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with Simba version 1.5.3. It is solved in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Look in My Tableau Repository\Logs -- either in log.txt or a related file.

If the error bubbled up any information from the driver to Tableau, there ought to be something in the log file. Entries are timestamped.

You can often see the query that was sent to the database server in the log prior to the the error message, and then try performing that query in a console tool outside of Tableau to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Sadly nothing has bubbled up to Tableau. This issue I am talking about occurs when I try to define the data source in Simba. Does Simba also have somewhere a logs folder?